# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars when finding crest_factor

Tags: python, list, numpy, warnings

I use following crest_factor function to find the crest factor of input "x". The input x is the 1D Numpy Array. However, the input x can sometimes become zero like x = np.array([0,0,0,0,0]). In that case, the crest factor formula will be 0.0/0.0. In this case, I will get "**RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars**" Please, can someone suggest me how to manipulate the math to overcome being "0.0 / 0.0"?

def crest_factor(x):
return np.max(np.abs(x))/np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(x)))

Comment: Why would crest factor even be valid when rms current is 0A? If no current flows, crest factor has no meaning. I guess it comes down to whether it's appropriate for 0/0 = 0 or 0/0 = 1 in this case, but mathematically it's undefined. My best guess is to permute rms current to be some arbitrarily small value, say 10^-9, in which case 0/(10^-9) = 0.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, crest factor is 1 whenever |peak current| = rms current. All values of x would need to be permuted the same amount in order for this to be true, i.e. `x = np.array([10^-9, 10^-9, 10^-9, 10^-9, 10^-9])]`